# outlook programming

Tags: outlook

How to add outlook custom fields in ms access?
Example:

```
 Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set item = objOutlook.CreateItem(2)  
 Set nms = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set fldContacts = nms.GetDefaultFolder(10)
 Set itms = fldContacts.Items 
 Set item = itms.Add
    item.FirstName = Me.FirstName
    ...
    item.Email1Address = Me.Email
    item.Fields("ClientId") = "Client1"
    item.Display
```

item.Fields("ClientId") = "Client1" -> This line does not work, any idea how to make this thing work? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to Outlook to test this now, but it looks like it should be

```
item.Fields("ClientId").Text = "Client1"
```

or

```
item.Fields("ClientId").Value = "Client1"
```

In other words, it looks like your code is trying to turn a control into a string ("Client1"), when you want to set the control's text (or value) to the string "Client1".

Comment: Thanks david for the response. But still i got "Run-time error '438' Object doesnt support this property or method"

Answer (score 0):

When you create the new item, you need to specify that it is a contact:

```
Set itm = itms.Add("IPM.Contact")
```

Comment: In this particular case. the problem is not the item type, but the fact that no item in the Outlook Object Model exposes Fields(). The type is fine - 10 is olFolderContacts, so calling Items.Add without any parameters returns ContactItem object.

Answer (score 0):

No Outlook item exposes Fields(). Use either Item.[PropertyAccessor.SetProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862751.aspx) or Item.[UserProperties.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867389.aspx)